# Why is this GridBagConstraints code not working?

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

Hello so I wanted to add text area, text field and a button to my panel. I wanted area to use 3/4 of height and full width, field to use 1/4 of height and 3/4 of width and a button to use 1/4 height and 1/4 width. I post a pic to show what I want to get. Code for this looks like:

```
// My JPanel class
public MainPanel() {
   setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
   add(area, new GBC(0, 0, 4, 3).setWeight(4,4).setFill(GBC.BOTH));
   add(field, new GBC(0, 3, 3, 1).setWeight(1,1).setFill(GBC.HORIZONTAL));
}
```

GBC is my class which inherits from GridBagConstraints class:

```
public class GBC extends GridBagConstraints {

   public GBC(int gridx, int gridy) {
      this.gridx = gridx;
      this.gridy = gridy;
      weightx = 100;
      weighty = 100;
   }

   public GBC(int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight) {
      this(gridx, gridy);
      this.gridwidth = gridwidth;
      this.gridheight = gridheight;
   }

   public GBC setFill(int fill) {
      this.fill = fill;
      return this;
   }
}
```

[image]

So the problem is that both area and field take half of height and a button is in the center, hidden under field... Look terrible anyway, how to solve if?

Comment: Post a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I posted the SSCCE. What more do you want?

Comment: That is not a SSCCE. How does that code compile???

Comment: The only code I didn't post is the code which creates JFrame, which in constrcutor creates MainPanel instance. It isn't the source for my problem for sure, so I didn't post it

Comment: But we can't execute your code to see the described behaviour. If we can see the behaviour we might understand the problem better. Yes, sometimes we can guess without a SSCCE but your job when you ask a question is to make it as easy as possible for us to help.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you. Next time I will post full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it should look like:

```
add(area, new GBC(0, 0, 4, 3).setWeight(4,4).setFill(GBC.BOTH));
add(field, new GBC(0, 3, 3, 1).setWeight(1,1).setFill(GBC.HORIZONTAL));
```

Also read about weightx and weighty, cause you're using them in wrong way

Answer (score 3):

`weightx` and `weighty` is what specifies how extra space is distributed. In your case, they both have the same value horizontally and vertically which is **100**.

Try to set `weightx` and `weighty` to **4** for `JTextArea` and set `weightx` and `weighty` to **1** for `JTextField`

You can check the doc for what does every field do in `GridBagConstraints`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html

Comment: @user2250795 u changed the comment?

Comment: @user2250795 Also, why was the other answer chosen when it is the same as mine and was answered later than mine? :S

Comment: @AdelBoutros And generally is a better answer (explains why the code was wrong)  (Nit pick - might be nice to link to Java 7 docs in the future ;))